# Root relative or relative url for .css and .js in asp.net masterpage

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, url, relative-path

I wonder what kind of url I should choose for local javascript and stylesheet files.

In Asp.net masterpage:

works:

```
<link href="../Content/Style/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

works:

```
<link href="/Content/Style/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

works:

```
<script src="/Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

this doesn't work correctly

```
 <script src="../Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

Whats the difference between:

```
<link href="../Content/Style/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and:

```
<script src="../Scripts/javascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use relative in the masterpage as the style sheets will be relative to the current url you are on (which can change depending on where the masterpage is served).  You should be able to use `~/` so that it also takes into account if it is an application or not

Comment: But it seems like href="../Content/Style/site.css" works on every url. src="../Scripts/javascript.js" does not work on every url.

Comment: When I look at the sourcecode in browser I can see that the relative url change depending on url.  href="../Content/Style/site.css" and href="../../Content/Style/site.css"

Comment: Just use the tilda otherwise if you ever run your site as an application under another site, you will have to re-code all your relative paths

Comment: ok. but I don't understand why and how my relative url works in href attribute in link-element...it automatically changes depending on url... src-attribute in script-element does not.

Comment: This pretty much explains it all https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/master-pages/urls-in-master-pages-cs - stylesheets relative urls in the head section have their url automatically resolved, scripts don't: While the `<link>` element's href attribute is relative, it's automatically converted to an appropriate path at runtime.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! :)